# Digital Ocean, connect to database with mySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, server, mysql-workbench, digital-ocean

I just started digital ocean server running ubuntu 14.04 LAMP server. I used my droplets IP address, root as the user and port 3306. I typed in the right password, but I can not for the life of me connect to my SQL on my server. ANy suggestions?

Error in mySQL Workbench:

```
Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at myIP:3306:
  Can't connect to MySQL server on 'myIP' (61)
```

Comment: Errors. Do you get them? Firewall. Is it on?

Comment: Maybe try the 33060 for the port instead of 3306

Comment: UFW is on, I made an exception for the port I typed into mySQL. Error is 61

Comment: Paste the whole error, please. We're not psychic. Have you created an account that allows remote access?

Comment: I have not created an account for remote access. I am pretty new to hosting my own server, just have root user set up for mySQL

Comment: Added the error in my above question

Comment: Looks like it's a mysql permission issue. I'm guessing the user Root on your mysql is only set up for "Localhost" or "127.0.0.1"?

Comment: "Can't connect' usually means the connection is refused, so I'd double-check your firewall rules and makes sure that port is open. As a note, it's usually a super bad idea to do this, so is it an option to use an `ssh` tunnel to connect instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find this answer here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-create-a-secure-connection-for-workbench-to-mysql

> MySQL Workbench works without any configuration necessary. When making
>   a new connection, select "Standard TCP/IP over SSH", then change the
>   SSH and MySQL parameters as necessary. (You should probably keep the
>   SQL server IP address as 127.0.0.1.)

Comment: I went through this process just yesterday. But it sounds like you're set. No need for any more input?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure if the root user is allow to connect from outside of Localhost, 127.0.0.1 or ::1 (which is localhost), if not, create the root user for connections outside localhost

```
  

CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'YourPassWord';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'YourPassWord' WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```

the @'%' means that now you can connect from any site,
or maybe you want to specify a IP address from which connect like:

```
.... 'root'@'yourIpAddress' .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the error the problem is in your connection not in your authentication.

Some things you should check first:

1. Root accounts usually are only allowed to be used by 127.0.0.7 by default in some setups. (Check @Jhonny Montoya answer for that.
2. Some hosting companies make it that the whole server or the 3306 port is only allowed to be used locally, allow your IP address in the remote table.

And remember that home users are very likely to have their IP changed every time their router restart so you need to re-add yourself when this happens.